# G++: Can __attribute__((__may_alias__)) be used for pointer to class instance rather than to class definition itself?

Tags: c++, gcc, g++, strict-aliasing

I'm looking to the answer to the following question: is `may_alias` suitable as attribute for pointer to an object of some class `Foo`? Or must it be used at class level only?

Consider the following code(it is based on a real-world example which is more complex):

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

#define alias_hack __attribute__((__may_alias__))

template <typename T>
class Foo
{
private:
    /*alias_hack*/ char Data[sizeof (T)];
public:
    /*alias_hack*/ T& GetT()
    {
        return *((/*alias_hack*/ T*)Data);
    } 
};

struct Bar
{
    int Baz;

    Bar(int baz)
      : Baz(baz)
    {}
} /*alias_hack*/; // <- uncommeting this line apparently solves the problem, but does so on class-level(rather than pointer-level)
// uncommenting previous alias_hack's doesn't help

int main()
{
    Foo<Bar> foo;
    foo.GetT().Baz = 42;
    cout << foo.GetT().Baz << endl;
}
```

Is there any way to tell gcc that single pointer `may_alias` some another?

BTW, please note that gcc detection mechanism of such problem is imperfect, so it is very easy to just make this warning go away without actually solving the problem.

Consider the following snippet of code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    long i = 42;
    long* iptr = &i;
    //(*(short*)&i) = 3; // with warning
    //(*(short*)iptr) = 3; // without warning
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Uncomment one of the lines to see the difference in compiler output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dimitar is correct.  may_alias is a *type* attribute.  It can only apply to a type, not an instance of the type.  What you'd like is what gcc calls a "variable attribute".  It would not be easy to disable optimizations for one specific pointer.  What would the compiler do if you call a function with this pointer?  The function is potentially already compiled and will behave based on the type passed to the function, not based on the address store in the pointer (you should see now why this is a type attribute)

Now depending on your code something like that might work:

```
#define define_may_alias_type(X) class X ## _may alias : public X { } attribute ((may_alias));
```

You'd just pass your pointer as `Foo_may_alias *` (instead of `Foo *`) when it might alias.  That's hacky though

Wrt your question about the warning, it's because `-Wall` defaults to `-Wstrict-aliasing=3` which is not 100% accurate.  Actually, `-Wstrict-aliasing` is never 100% accurate but depending on the level you'll get more or less false negatives (and false positives).  If you pass `-Wstrict-aliasing=1` to gcc, you'll see a warning for both

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer - sorry, no.

__attrbite__ gives instructions to the compiler. Objects exist in the memory of the executed program. Hence nothing in __attribute__ list can relate to the run-time execution.

Comment: I don't understand. I don't know gcc's handling mechanism of strict aliasing(and related stuff, like this `may_alias` attribute), but I see no problem to disable some optimization for reads/writes that use one specific pointer.

Comment: Or do you imply that, for example for the following snippet of code `Foo foo; Foo alias_hack* fooPtr;` writing using fooPtr and then reading using foo directly may lead to wrong value because of optimizations? But again, I see no problem with that, I didn't mark `foo` with necessary attribute, but I did this for fooPtr.

Comment: Maybe I'm just missing something

Comment: Ok. Probably I am missing the whole point of the question. But let me put a few thoughts: alias in type cast won't do anything, the attribute is intended only for use in type declaration. The attribute is used to alias types, not pointers. However you could try playing around with the optimisation level (-O1 vs -O2) to see how it goes, check -fstrict-aliasing option too.

Comment: Short answer is fine(and I'm going to accept yours unless there will be more detailed explaination from someone else), but it would be great to understand why gcc can't apply may_alias to single ptr. If you have any references or can write more detailed explanation, please do it, that would be absolutely awesome.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't find any solid information on the web to refer you to. All I have written here is stuff I remember from quite old projects. Will check with some people though if they can provide some extra details.